# how to override Scss for specific page for specific button in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am not able to override the scss for specific button on page.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-esc8ua?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

```
   button {
       &.optgroup {
          &.input-wrapper {
            padding-left:10px !important;
          }
       }
     }
```

```
<button ion-item class="optgroup">Hello i want to apply css to this button</button>

   <button ion-item>i dont want to modify this button</button>
```

i want to apply padding-left:10px to inner of text of first button

Solved:

```
.optgroup {
        & > div.item-inner {
          padding-left:6px !important;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an scss file under the home directory and refer it from the Home Component like this:

**home.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  styleUrls: [ 'home.scss' ]
})
```

and in the **home.scss**:

```
.optgroup ::content {
  padding-left:100px;
}
```

Comment: This will add padding-left:100px to both the button, i want to add padding-left to first button of .item-inner

Comment: just change the `button` selector into `.optgroup`. i've edited my post. check it out.

Comment: This will move entire thing including line bar.